# How to draw a filled rectangle in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox, rectangles

How to draw a filled rectangle using PDFBox?

I just can't find the right function of the [PDFBox API documentation](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

I want to draw a filled rectangle under the first row of a table:

```
public static void drawTable(PDPage page, PDPageContentStream contentStream,
                            float y, float margin,
                            String[][] content) throws IOException {
final int rows = content.length;
final int cols = content[0].length;
final float firstRowHeight = 160f;
final float rowHeight = 20f;
final float colWidth = 15f; //tableWidth/(float)cols;
final float tableWidth = colWidth * cols; //page.findMediaBox().getWidth()-(2*margin);
final float tableHeight = rowHeight * rows + firstRowHeight - rowHeight;    
final float cellMargin= 5f;

/*PDRectangle rectangle = new PDRectangle();
rectangle.setLowerLeftX(10);
rectangle.setLowerLeftY(10);
rectangle.setUpperRightX(10);
rectangle.setUpperRightY(10);
page.setMediaBox(rectangle);
page.setCropBox(rectangle);*/

//draw the rows
float nexty = y ;
for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
    contentStream.drawLine(margin,nexty,margin+tableWidth,nexty);
    if (i<=0) {
    nexty-= firstRowHeight;
    } else {
    nexty-= rowHeight;
    }
}

//draw the columns
float nextx = margin;
for (int i = 0; i <= cols; i++) {
    contentStream.drawLine(nextx,y,nextx,y-tableHeight);
    nextx += colWidth;
}

//now add the text
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD,8);

float textx = margin+cellMargin;
float texty = y-15;
//int o = content.length;

for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < content[i].length; j++){
        String text = content[i][j];
        contentStream.beginText();
        if (i<=0) {
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty-140);
        contentStream.setTextRotation(90*Math.PI*0.25,textx+5,texty-140);
        } else {
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty);
        contentStream.setTextRotation(90*Math.PI*0.25,textx+5,texty-3); 
        }
        contentStream.drawString(text);
        contentStream.endText();
        textx += colWidth;
    }
    if (i<=0) {
    texty-=firstRowHeight;
    } else {
    texty-=rowHeight;
    }
    textx = margin+cellMargin;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called [fillRect](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html#fillRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) in PDPageContentStream that does the trick.

Answer (score 19):

This is how you can draw a rectangle in PDFBox 2:

```
void drawRect(PDPageContentStream content, Color color,
              Rectangle rect, boolean fill) {
    content.addRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    if (fill) {
        content.setNonStrokingColor(color);
        content.fill();
    } else {
        content.setStrokingColor(color);
        content.stroke();
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int startX = 20;
int startY = 30;
int width = 40;
int height = 50;
var color = Color.BLUE;
var rect = new java.awt.Rectangle(startX, startY, width, height);
// Draw a blue filled rectangle
drawRect(content, color, rect , true);
```